# Operators whose spectrum has a finite number of connected component

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, spectral-theory

Assume that $H$ is  a  separable Hilbert space. Let $Q$ be the set of all operators$T \in B(H)$  such that  the spectrum of $T$  has  a  finite number of  connected component. Is $Q$ a subvector space of $B(H)$? What id $\bar{Q}$, the closure of $Q$? What is the closure of the span of $Q$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E=\{1,1/2,1/3,\cdots\}$ and let $\mu_{a}$ be the finite atomic meausre on $[0,1]$ that is supported on $E$ with $\mu\{1/n\}=1/n^{2}$. Let $\mu = \mu_{a}+m$ where $m$ is Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.

Let $X=L^{2}_{\mu}[0,1]$. Let $\chi$ be the characteristic function of $E$, and define operators $A, B \in \mathcal{L}(X)$ by
$$
                    Af = xf(x),\;\;\;   Bf =x\{1-\chi(x)\}f(x).
$$
Then $\sigma(A)=[0,1]$ and $\sigma(B)=[0,1]$, but $\sigma(A-B)=E\cup\{0\}$. So you have two operators with connected spectrum and the sum of the two has spectrum consisting of infinitely many disjoint components.

Comment: Thank you for your very interesting example. i have another question which is some how related to the above. Are there some results about the comparision of $\mu (sp(A+B))$  and $\mu (sp (A))$  and $\mu (sp (B))$  where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue  measure of real line  and $A,B$  are self adjoint operators on a Hilbert space?

Comment: @AliTaghavi : That's a fairly broad topic because the Schrodinger operators $(A+B)f=-\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}f + Vf$ fall into that category, for example. Lots of things can happen in general.